# Play ws request timeout

Tags: scala, playframework, ws

I am recieving an error

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Read timeout to {url} after 120000 ms
```

In my settings I have set:
play.ws.timeout.request = 5 minutes
play.ws.timeout.idle = 5 minutes

But these still aren't working.

Comment: Show us the code you wrote which is triggering this error. Is that a Play application or standalone Play WS client?

Answer (score 0):

In my `application.conf` I will define a timeout like this:

```
someRequestTimeout = "45 seconds"
```

and then in my code I'd write

```
wsClient
    .url("http://example.com")

    .withRequestTimeout(config.getDuration("someRequestTimeout"))
    
    .post(somePayload)
    .map { response => ??? }
```